# Verificar si hay una coma y sustituirla por un punto

Tags: java, android

Tengo un EditText donde recojo lo introducido en el cajetin y estoy tratando de verificar de si introdujo comas, letras donde solo se permite un formato como este : 123.11

Si el usuario introduce el parametro distinto a un valor de tipo Float la aplicacion se rompe. Y no se como evitarlo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aunque hace poco que estoy programando con *android* creo que puedes evitar que el usuario introduzca letras o comas aplicando                 `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` en el *EditText* que quieras.

Un ejemplo:

```
    <EditText
       android:id="@+id/editxt_loquesea"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
```

Espero que te sirva!

Answer (score 3):

```
public double getValor(String texto){
    if(texto.contains(",")){
        return Double.parseDouble(texto.replace(",", ".").trim());
    }
    return Double.parseDouble(texto.trim());
}
```

La función recibe como parametro el valor como un String, y primero verificamos si ese String contiene comas.

Si las tiene, entonces reemplazamos las comas de la cadena por un punto y retornamos ese valor convirtiéndolo a double.

En el caso de que no tenga comas, entonces sólo retorna el valor del parámetro convirtiéndolo a double.

Comment: La funcion recibe como parametro el valor como un String, y primero verificamos si ese String contiene comas (,) , si las tiene entonces reemplazamos las comas de la cadena por un punto (.) y retornamos ese valor convirtiendolo a double, en el caso de que no tenga comas(,) entonces solo retorna el valor del parametro convirtiendolo a double.

Comment: para agregar información en tu respuesta, encontrarás el enlace para [edit] al pié de la misma

Answer (score 1):

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    double doubleValue = 0;
    if (s != null) {
        try {
            doubleValue = Double.parseDouble(s.toString().replace(',', '.'));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            //Error
        }
    }
    //Hacer cualquier cosa con el doblevalue
}
```

Con esta función como podrás observar sustituye comas por puntos, así no deberías tener ningún problema.